# TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "conv1d" (type Conv1D)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a project **"News Classification"**. Where the model has to classify(multi-class classification problem) a given text into **business, entertainment, politics, sport and tech.**

I am using **TensorFlow==2.7.0** on **Google Colab**. I had trained 7 different models. After, training and made prediction on it. When compared to all models,  *Conv1d* performed the best. The best performing model saved  `model_2.save('saved_model/my_model')`.It has done well till here.

But, When I want to load the saved model using the code

`loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')` then, I am getting the below exception:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-c92edaf0db7f> in <module>()
----> 1 load_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')
      2 # load_model.preditct(val_sentences)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    547       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
    548     except TypeError:
--> 549       raise TypeError(f"Failed to convert elements of {values} to Tensor. "
    550                       "Consider casting elements to a supported type. See "
    551                       "https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes "

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "conv1d" (type Conv1D).

Failed to convert elements of tf.RaggedTensor(values=tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 128), dtype=float32), row_splits=Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)), row_splits=Tensor("conv1d/Conv1D/RaggedExpandDims/RaggedFromUniformRowLength/RowPartitionFromUniformRowLength/mul:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 128), dtype=float32), row_splits=Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Could share the colab gist or reproducible code snippet. Thanks

Comment: @TFer The same error occurs when trying to save and load the model from here: https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_from_scratch/ It appears to be an issue with the TextVectorization layer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add .h5 on the file name. You need to add .h5 to the end of your file name.
Instead of:

`model_2.save('saved_model/my_model')`
try

```
model_2.save('saved_model/my_model.h5')
#Notice the .h5 -------------------^
```

You will also nee to change `loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')`
to `loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model.h5')`

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed in tensorflow 2.9. upfrading tf version will be helpful
more information :
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/d3b6494e82085a397bad2260a43ea6769aa20f5d

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).